# "zend_mm_heap corrupted" with PHP 7.1

Tags: php, php-7.1

I am testing my "Arrayy"-library via Travis CI but it crashes when I run the tests with PHP 7.1 === error "zend_mm_heap corrupted" ... How can I debug this? Any idea why this happen?

- result: https://travis-ci.org/voku/Arrayy/jobs/217634096#L981
- test: https://github.com/voku/Arrayy/blob/master/tests/ArrayyTest.php#L2967
- code: https://github.com/voku/Arrayy/blob/master/src/Arrayy.php#L1952

Comment: Looks like you've run into a bug in PHP. https://bugs.php.net/how-to-report.php

Comment: Reported: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=74361

Comment: Thanks for the fix! :) | https://github.com/php/php-src/commit/c8034514edadbafc4376f107e2a4ba52b7b17ff4